# How to make PhpStorm work with a remote local copy of a remote repository?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

This question is related to a complex project where I was hired and I cannot change the existing system.

The test development environment is a server with a local copy of a remote git repository. It's like `git clone` was done on the server.

But we are not working on the server, but on a local machine, where we would like to have a complete copy of what is on the test server. Of course, within the framework of the PhpStorm editor.

Ie: I edit the file and it is automatically edited on the server.
I commit locally on my local machine, but in fact the commit is done on a test environment.

Is it really possible to do this?

Comment: Ie: I edit the file and it is automatically edited on the server. I commit locally on my local machine, but in fact the commit is done on a test environment. on this part, how the code was pulled from test envoronment, was it git pull?

Comment: You could set the Dev server as a Git remote _but_ I guess you're working in a team and you don't want everyone working on the same branch and constantly overwrite others work which would happen because your Dev server can only use a single branch at a time.